# Keyboard shortcut Shift + Ctrl + Escape does not work

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 w/ Unity. I like how the Task Manager shows up in Windows with
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>. So I tried creating a similar keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu with the command `gnome-terminal -e htop`.

Nothing happens when invoking that shortcut. However, if I assign a different combination, say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> reserved or something? It used to work perfectly in 13.10 and before.

Comment: (1) Trying in a terminal, make sure the command works. (2) Why don't you use `gnome-system-monitor` instead?

Comment: @AliNa: Regarding (1), The command (obviously) works in the terminal, and it works if the shortcut combination is different, as mentioned. As for (2), I like `htop`.

Comment: I have opened a bug report: [#1350527](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1350527)

Comment: I've just run into precisely the same error. I'll add that you can use dconf-editor to view the actual shortcut configuration live at /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings. Not found a workaround, yet, though. A temporary workaround for me is bind Ctrl-Shift-ScrollLk

Comment: Ah, it works with regular GNOME, just Unity appears to break it.

Comment: @sehe unity is a compiz plugin. use and enable the ccsm command options plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use CCSM to assign the command and keybinding and it will work in Unity.

To get Compiz Config Setting Manager do the following:

- Open the Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra -y
  ```
- Open CCSM
- Select the <kbd>commands</kbd> option
- Assign the command on line 0

Select the <kbd>Keybinding</kbd> tab and assign the hotkeys you like to trigger the command.

Comment: @snoop: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/549111/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**
From tomorrow on all your bad edits will be rejected by default.  Please do a thorough job or do none at all... Pretty please???

Comment: @Fabby:your edits are perfect as your are experience person. My some of edits might be not as per expectations but you can reject it and improve it. I am still learning this.

Comment: No worries: You received plenty of examples by now, so I'm convinced the qualities of your edits will skyrocket! **;-)**

Comment: I have 1 query. Is it allow to add our sentence if someone has done grammatical mistake or unable to express his/her problem?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: I don't think this answer can work for short cuts with the esc key. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018817/527764)