# Custom shortcut Ctrl + Shift + Esc doesn't fire the event

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-monitor

For some reason my custom shortcut for the System Monitor that I created according to this instruction does not work.
[Is there a default shortcut for System Monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812069/is-there-a-default-shortcut-for-system-monitor)

When I press it, it just does nothing. Any ideas?

My shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason there is a problem using <kbd>Esc</kbd> key within Custom shortcuts. Here is the same (unanswered) question: [Ubuntu 16.04 escape key doesn't work in custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961185/ubuntu-16-04-escape-key-doesnt-work-in-custom-keyboard-shortcut). I found also this question: [Keyboard shortcut Shift + Ctrl + Escape does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/489418/566421), where in the comments [@Cas](https://askubuntu.com/users/8570/cas) says: *I have opened a bug report: [#1350527](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1350527)*.

Мy suggestion is to use another key combination, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and command to be executed: `gnome-system-monitor`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very strange problem with esc indeed. Works now with a different shortcut.

Comment: @WilliFischer, it is already reported as bug: [#1350527](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1350527).

Comment: I see. Unresolved for four years, though :D
Will check it once in  a while. Until then, I just use another shortcut. Thanks again for your very thorough answer