# Custom keyboard shortcut for terminal command `htop` not working

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, reboot, system-monitor, htop

On Ubuntu 18.04 I can setup custom keyboard shortcuts to run terminal commands via:

```
Settings > Devices > Keyboard > +
```

> **Name**: htop keyboard shortcut
>   **Command**: htop
>   **ShortCut**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

This usually works without issue when I've created shortcuts for other terminal commands, other than `htop`. When I try and issue the `htop` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> it just doesn't work.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and the htop system monitor doesn't initiate on my system. What's wrong? All the other keyboard shortcuts I've created in this manner are working fine.

Comment: Hello, have you tried to use another combination? Please review this topic: [Custom shortcut Ctrl + Shift + Esc doesn't fire the event](https://askubuntu.com/q/1018814/566421)

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks for that recommendation. I tried the recommended safe `Ctrl+Alt+Z` combination in that answer and that didn't work either. Perhaps it's a problem with the `htop` command?

Comment: I tried a few other combinations. They too didn't work in Ubuntu 18.04. `Ctrl+Super+Del` does work to launch `htop` in Kubuntu 18.04. So rather than it being "a problem with the `htop` command", I guess it's a GNOME issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***WorkAround***

use the command `gnome-terminal -- htop` instead of htop

Verified on Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why some terminal commands require the `gnome-terminal --` prefix?

Comment: I have tried different combinations of shortcut keys other than ctrl+super+del and nothing worked for `htop` command.. but when I type `htop` in terminal it worked.. so the workaround is to open gnome-terminal and then run `htop` command.. the prefix opens terminal and then runs the command..