# How to I start ranger directly from my file manager?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How do I make `ranger` start directly from my file manager, instead of first opening the terminal and then starting the application?

I have written this below code in my `.desktop` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ranger
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'ranger'
Terminal=True
Type=Application
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. How do I fix it?

I tried adding `bash` at the end like this:

```
Exec="/bin/bash -c 'ranger';bash"
```

But, this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: VTC because "I am using ElementaryOS, which is a flavor of ubuntu."

Comment: This site only supports Ubuntu and its official flavors. Elementary OS is off-topic here.

Comment: Elementary OS is also ubuntu itself.
Mr.DK Bose, why are you so rude in all your posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
#!/bin/bash
```

from the beginning of file.

Change the `Terminal` line to:

```
Terminal=true
```

(lowercase `true`).

And

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'ranger'
```

to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/ranger
```

or whatever is the full path of the `ranger` command.

Another option would be to change the `Exec` command like this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --active -- /usr/bin/ranger
```

If you need full screen terminal, you can try the `--maximize` and `--full-screen` options of `gnome-terminal`. **Please, close all terminals before testing!**

To find out the full path of `gnome-terminal` run the command:

```
whereis gnome-terminal
```

Comment: ok, this worked but it looks very ugly. :((


This is how it looks like when executed from inside the terminal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTL1n.png

and

This is how it looks like when executed your way: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CoUi.png

So how do I get it to look like how it looks when executed from inside the terminal?

Comment: btw, my only mistake was using capital T in true, other things kept the same worked as well. :)) I just tried it. :) I am not sure which is a better approach though.

Comment: Can you change the `Exec` line like this? `Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --active -- /usr/bin/ranger`

Comment: this one isn't working. :(

Comment: also, do you know how to start ranger in full screen by default whenever I click the shortcut? instead of having to make it full screen everytime I start it?

Comment: I just checked inside my usr/bin folder to see if I actually have gnome-terminal in there but there isn't any gnome-terminal file in my usr/bin. :(

Comment: I am using ElementaryOS, which is a flavor of ubuntu.

Comment: You can try the `--maximize` and `--full-screen` options of `gnome-terminal`. Please, close all terminals before testing! Try `whereis gnome-terminal` to find out the full path of `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I don't have gnome-terminal in my system. :((

Comment: but I do have terminology, terminator, about 4-5 others. I can name them all if you need.

Comment: any idea how to start this in other terminals like Terminology or Terminator?

Comment: Since you do not have `gnome-terminal`, I presume you can use the other terminals (actually, the one that you are using regularly). I do not have these terminals installed, so I cannot help you further. But, you can easily make your own tests by first reading the relevant `man` page of your terminal.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. :) really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Ranger

Exec=gnome-terminal -- ranger

Type=Application
```

works for me.

Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/1183018/248158

Comment: sorry, this didn't work for me but the above answer worked.

Comment: well, but it looks very ugly and is not what I expected. so I am waiting on the other answer's owner to reply back on how to fix the ugliness.

Comment: if you could please see my reply to the first answer and tell me how to fix the ugliness, that would be really helpful.